# Mounting a ready SSD onto a pod in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage

I will be running a pod with persistent SSD. I already have the disk ready (created from snapshot)
I want to attach this disk to a pod. So far, I have been creating the pod in this manner

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: geth-stateful
  namespace: dev
spec:
  serviceName: geth-dev-service
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: geth-node
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: geth-node
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: geth-node
        image: asia.gcr.io/indiesquare-dev/geth-node:v1.8.12
        ports:
        volumeMounts:
        - name: geth-chaindata
          mountPath: /var/tmp
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "13Gi"
            cpu: "5000m"
          limits:
            memory: "14Gi"
            cpu: "5500m"   
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: geth-chaindata
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 500Gi
```

However, this always creates a new disk. Is there a way to provide an already existing disk as `volumeMounts`?

Answer (score 0):

If you claim a volume without first having a PVC on GKE, Google Cloud Platform will provision a new disk for you each time to meet the claim.

Since you already have the disk created and prepared, you want to configure a [Persistent Volume first that uses the preexisting disk](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#using_preexisting_persistent_disks_as_persistentvolumes) and a Persistent Volume Claim to consume it.